# How can i split the text from a conversation into sender and reciver

Tags: javascript, photo, analyzer, tesseract.js

I am currently trying to output all text from an image. I made this work using tesseract.js but now i faced a problem. I dont know how to analyze a conversation photo. If I just put it thru tesseract it outputs all the text but I need to somehow split it into the sender and reciver

For example with the default tesseract function it will output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZrxp.png)

I dont think I can make it to the party?
Are you sure?

But I need it something like

reciver: I dont think I can make it to the party
Sender: Are you sure?

Or something like this so I can distinguish them somehow

Any idea on how I could do it? It would help me a lot. Thanks in advance

The only thing I thought I could "split" the image in half and read everythin on the left as reciver and everything on the right as sender but I have this problem where in some convos some text is bigger and passes the half of the screen

Comment: The screen is typically not divided in a 50-50 ratio but in a 2/3 and 1/3 ratio. This means that the maximum width for both sides is 2/3, and their texts are never placed next to each other.